# Install Java 6 besides Java 7 on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: java

Java 6 could be installed besides Java 7 on ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets ask aptitude:

```
aptitude why-not openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-6-jdk
Unable to find a reason to remove openjdk-6-jdk.
```

(the first line reads: aptitude why not install openjdk-6-jdk if I have openjdk-7-jdk installed)

So, the short answer is: yes.

Long answer: if you use apt-get to do it you can. If you try to do the same with Oracle's Java, prepare to have some problems.

Comment: The reason is Play framework needs Java 6 and I don't want remove Java 7

Comment: @AmirAsaad sorry but I don't get it. I told you that the answer is yes as long as you use apt-get.

Comment: No if you use apt-get.